# number_format inside <input type="number"> tag does not work for numbers above 1000?

Tags: php, html

I've run into a bug within my PHP application that is really doing my head in.

When using `number_format()` on a number, inside an HTML input (number) tag, the number doesn't show if it's higher than 1000! It does work, however, if I set the HTML input type to 'text'.

Observe the following code:

```
    <input type='number' value="<?php echo number_format(1000,0); ?>" /><br /> <!-- displays nothing -->
    <input type='text' value="<?php echo number_format(1000,0); ?>" /><br /> <!-- displays 1,000 -->
    <input type='number' value="<?php echo number_format(500,0); ?>" /><br /> <!-- displays 500 -->
    <input type='text' value="<?php echo number_format(500,0); ?>" /><br /> <!-- displays 500 -->
```

I found a "solution", by removing the 1000 separator:

```
    number_format(1000,0,'.','')
```

...however for big numbers, I really need the 1000 separator for visibility.

Does anyone know a way of getting around this? I'm hitting my head in the wall here!

My fiddle: http://viper-7.com/vg3LyW

Comment: Don't overcomplicate stuff: all you have is `<input type="number" value="1,000">` and `1,000` is not a valid number for a computer.

Comment: The code I put above is simply for clarity. I'm actually using a variable name instead of 1000, and the number always varies.
E.g.: number_format($variable,0)

Comment: maybe interesting? [HTML5 number inputs – Comma and period as decimal marks](https://www.aeyoun.com/posts/html5-input-number-localization.html)

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to have a thousands separator with the native input field: https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/html5-input-number-localization.html

If you really need it, you have to use some kind of JavaScript replacement.